# Print inside async function

Tags: rust, twitter

```
pub async fn twitterauth() -> String {
    let con_token = egg_mode::KeyPair::new("public_token", "secret_token");
    let request_token = egg_mode::auth::request_token(&con_token, "oob").await.unwrap();
    let auth_url = egg_mode::auth::authorize_url(&request_token);

    return auth_url;
}

fn output() -> impl Future<Output = String> {
    twitterauth()
}

fn main() {    
    let authurl = output();    
    println!("{}", authurl);
}
```

I am having trouble returning this variable `auth_url` to the user by printing it in the console or the GUI.

When I put the printing statement in the async function, nothing happens and I can't call the function in `main()` either.

Right now it gives me this error:

```
`impl Future<Output = String>` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
```

[If i use this approach, it throws me another error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyLFK.png)

Comment: Please do not use text for images. Also, post the full error from `cargo check`, not your IDE.

Answer (score 4):

Your `twitterauth()` function isn't actually run.

`async` functions don't run when you call them. They return a future. Only when this future is `.await`ed they will run.

The problem is that you cannot `.await` in `main()`. The solution is to plug in a runtime, like [`tokio`](https://docs.rs/tokio).

With it, it is as simple as:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {    
    let authurl = output().await;
    println!("{}", authurl);
}
```

Comment: A small pitfall with plugging tokio in is that you have to remember not just to add it to your `Cargo.toml`, but also enable the `full` feature of it with `tokio = { version = "1.19", features = ["full"] }` to be able to use `tokio::main`